# How to make globally callable python program?

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-interface, setuptools

I wrote a module and created a setup.py to install the module:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mymodule',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test', 'test.*']),
    include_package_data=True,
    platforms='any',
    install_requires=[
        'lxml==3.3.5',
        'Pillow==3.0.0',
        'requests==2.2.1',
        'xmltodict==0.10.1',
        'pdfrw==0.2',
        'python-dotenv==0.4.0',
        'boto==2.39.0'
    ],
)
```

In the same module I also wrote a command line interface for the module using [getopt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html). I want to make this command line interface globally available so that any user on the system can do things like:

```
$ mycliprogram -i inputfile.xml -o outputfile.txt
```

Does anybody know how I can include `mycliprogram.py` in setup.py so that anybody on the system can use it from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `console-scripts` (as Sergey suggested) or the `entry_points` parameter in your `setup()`:

```
  entry_points={
      'console_scripts': [
          'mycliprogram=mymodule:whatever',
      ],
  },
```

This will create a `myclyprogram` wrapper, which is accessible via `$PATH` and it will call `whatever` in `mymodule`. So if you install your module via `pip` or `setup.py`, you'll be able to call `mycliprogram` with whatever options you defined directly from the command line prompt.

More information: [Command Line Scripts – Python Packaging Tutorial](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html?highlight=entry_points)

Answer (score 2):

I'll quote the [documentation](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html):

The first approach is to write your script in a separate file, such as you might write a shell script:

```
funniest/
    funniest/
        __init__.py
        ...
    setup.py
    bin/
        funniest-joke
    ...
```

Then we can declare the script in setup() like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    scripts=['bin/funniest-joke'],
    ...
)
```

When we install the package, setuptools will copy the script to our PATH and make it available for general use.:

`$ funniest-joke`

Comment: Please consider adding some additional information to your answer. A link-only answer can be completely useless in future if the link is broken.